# how to change a project type from dll to standard windows application or win32 application type in visual c++ VS2005

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

I have done a dll project in VC++ (VS2008). I want to change it to a standard exe file project. Is there someone can help me in that.

I tried with changing the project type in the Configuration Properties -> Configuration Type to Application (.exe) and Linker -> Output File to $(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).exe and even the Linker -> System to Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)

Comment: Create new project and copy existing code to it.

Comment: Yes, that's how you do it.  And write WinMain().  Completely unclear what you need help with.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I tried copying the codes but somehow it throws lots of errors from the precompiled header files.

Answer (score 2):

Please change the following settings to change the project type.

Settings->General->Configuration Type

[image]

Settings->Linker->General->Output File

[image]

Comment: Thank you Retna, I tried these and able to compile it without any errors. But when I open the compile .exe file it says "Not a Valid Win32 Application." When I press Control + F5 it says "Unable to start program ......exe"